# Editing MP3/Wav Files in a Flutter App (Dart)

Tags: dart, flutter, voice-recording

Is it possible in a Flutter App to "concatenate" sound files without calling Swift/Java code to handle it for me? (Partially because I don't know Swift, and partially because I haven't figured out ffmpeg yet) The microphone provides either mp3 or wav files, and either works fine for me.

I'm attempting to make a Recording app that has more functionality than the ones I've previously found. Specifically, I want it to be able to pause the recording for an indefinite amount of time, and start again WITHOUT creating two files for the user to save -- it should combine them and save it later as a single file.

Comment: The short answer is _yes_, Dart is a turing complete language and you could say, port ffpmeg to Dart. The long answer is that it is probably _much_ easier to use an existing native library (Swift/Java) than port something like that.

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look about this

[medcorder_audio](https://pub.dev/packages/medcorder_audio#-example-tab-)

and for splitting

[audiocutter](https://pub.dev/packages/audiocutter#-installing-tab-)

Comment: Link only answers are not considered good practice. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer